# How do I search in files (for example in Java files) in Vista?

Tags: java, search, windows-vista

Is there a way or tool for Vista I can use to search for content in Java files? (I do not have an Eclipse project set up for it)

I used to be able to do it easily in the windows search tool when I had Windows 2000.

Edit: I have already enabled "search file contents" and added additional file types as recommended by xsl and Grant Wagner, the search still returns no results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I just use [BareGrep](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baregrep/) (and previously, [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/)), which is fast, supports regexes and show lines that match.
[grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin) is nice too (can replace strings) but doesn't show lines.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of search tools. Simplest and smallest is the GNU grep.

I personnally use Far (for many things, not just search).

Comment: Why on earth would you recommend a bunch of third party tools for something that is built into the OS?

Comment: @Kristian: Did you happen to turn off the indexing service or something? This should work fine right from the standard windows search.

Comment: I hade already enabled "search file contents" and added additional file types as recommended by xsl and Grant Wagner, the search still for some reason returns no results...

Comment: Besides, the built-in search is painfully slow on my Vista.

Answer (score 0):

How to add additional file types to Vista's indexing is explained at [Watching The Net](http://www.watchingthenet.com/add-remove-file-types-to-windows-vista-search-index.html) and [the How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-a-new-file-type-to-indexing-in-windows-vista/).